# Why does the button tag automatically vertical align text

Tags: html, css

Even after setting `display:block` on a `button` element, the text inside is still vertically centered, unlike a div. What causes this behavior and how can it be prevented?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7vx4ucj8/

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup Added example

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Your first question. Every browsers has a predefined styles for html elements based on a W3C specifications.

Comment: So no way to make a button behave like a div then?

Comment: Unfortunately You cannot overwrite the default button behavior. You can hack them like `Nenad Vracar` write.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this http://jsfiddle.net/7vx4ucj8/1/

**HTML**

```
<div>Div</div>
<button><span>Button</span></button>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

button {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```